# Problema al pulsar un floating button

Tags: java, android, listview

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para Android, el caso es que tengo un `floating button` que cuando lo pulso me despliega varias opciones
El caso es que cuando le pulso me despliega las opciones y ocupan un `ListView` y cuando quiero pulsar una de esas opciones me pulsa el `item` del `listview` sobre el que esta.

Inserto una [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bFGk.jpg) como ejemplo

¿Sabéis algún modo de evitar esto? Llevo unos días con ello y no soy capaz.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando la parte del código donde estás teniendo problemas

Comment: No entiendo que quieres evitar. ¿Quieres que te muestre un ListView pero que no haga nada cuando clique en algún ítem?

Comment: No, el listview me lo muestra bien, pero tengo un floating button que ocupa parte del list view, y cuando pulso sobre el button me pulsa el item de debajo.He añadido una foto del problema, por si se entiende mejor

Comment: ¿Tiene asignado algo el floating button?

Comment: @David_helo tiene un onclick listener  con un intent al pulsar..te refieres a eso?

Comment: Hola @alamoalberto95 es importante revises [ask] y realices el [tour] , agrega más información o detalles y agrega el código esencial de tu pregunta para tratar de reproducirlo.

Answer (score 1):

Okey,lo tendré en cue ta para las siguientes,gracias. Lo he solucionado,el problema era que había una "capa" encima de otra y no permitía pulsar la de abajo, lo he solucionado con un RelativeLayout